# Как сделать резиновый логотип с помощью bootstrap-3 в joomla?

Tags: joomla, bootstrap

Суть такова: нужно, чтобы логотип масштабировался в зависимости от размера окна браузера, дело в том, что логотип загружается через административную панель joomla. Как его сделать резиновым? В bootstrap 2 был row-fluid, он сам все подгонял, а теперь это вручную делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря, надо смотреть пример вёрстки, но если логотип просто вставляется картинкой, то этой картинке надо присвоить класс **img-responsive**.

```
<div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-4 logo"> <?php if ($tmpl_logo) : ?> <a href="/" ><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tmpl_logo);?>" alt="MYLOGO" **class="img-responsive"** /></a> <?php endif;?> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 logo">
<?php if ($tmpl_logo) : ?>
<a href="/" ><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tmpl_logo);?>" alt="MYLOGO"/></a>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: @Amlo, выше смотрите комментарий

Comment: Большое спасибо, ребят! Все заработало. Все-таки в Bootstrap-3 немножко усложнилось все, в отличие от 2-го.